# Pair without replacement

Tags: python, pandas, merge, duplicates

I have a dataframe of treatments and I want to pair these up with suitable controls. Each control can only be assigned to one treatment.

The treatments match with controls if the group is the same and the control score is within +/- 10% of the treated score.

I need to do this pairing so that as many treatments as possible get a suitable control assigned, with the control only appearing once.

Essentially I'm looking to do a 'Pair without replacement'.

```
df_treatment = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['a-1', 'a-2', 'a-3', 'b-1', 'b-2'],
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A'],
    'score': [200, 230, 210, 390, 202]})

df_control = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['x-1', 'y-9', 'y-8', 'y-1', 'x-2', 'x-3', 'x-1'],
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'score': [180, 218, 210, 220, 400, 380, 210]})

# Merge to create every pair where they match on group

df_merged = pd.merge(df_treatment, df_control, on='group',
                     suffixes=('_treated', '_control'), how='left')

# Filter for where they match on score criteria

df_matched = df_merged[
(df_merged['score_control'].between(df_merged['score_treated'] * 0.9, df_merged['score_treated'] * 1.1))
    ][['id_treated', 'group', 'id_control']]

df_matched

    id_treated  group   id_control
0   a-1         A       x-1
1   a-1         A       y-9
2   a-1         A       y-8
4   a-2         A       y-9
5   a-2         A       y-8
6   a-3         C       y-1
9   a-3         C       x-1
11  b-1         C       x-2
12  b-1         C       x-3
15  b-2         A       y-9
16  b-2         A       y-8
```

From here I want to get a dataframe where `id_control` is not repeated, but keep as many unique values of `id_treated` as possible.

So in the example above we would produce

```
| | id_treated |  group  | id_control|  
|-| --------   | ------- | ------    |
|0| a-1        | A       | x-1       |
|3| a-2        | A       | y-9       |
|4| a-3        | C       | y-1       |
|5| b-1        | C       | x-2       |
|6| b-1        | C       | x-3       |
|8| b-2        | A       | y-8       |
```

I've tried using

```
df_matched.drop_duplicates(subset='id_control', keep='first')
```

but this would keep all of a-1's pairs and removes the a-2 and b-2 pairings, leaving fewer treatments to compare:

```
id_treated  group   id_control
0   a-1     A   x-1
1   a-1     A   y-9
2   a-1     A   y-8
6   a-3     C   y-1
11  b-1     C   x-2
12  b-1     C   x-3
```

Edited to include df_control being able to have control_id appear multiple times with different group and score values.

Comment: Beside the point, but you could simplify the +/-10% part: `df_merged['score_control'].between(df_merged['score_treated'] * 0.9, df_merged['score_treated'] * 1.1)`

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you have the treated_id column and you want to keep as many treated_id as possible with each having a unique control_id value and remove the duplicates.

To achieve that use pandas `groupby()` function

```
df.groupby(["threated_id", "control_id"]).first().reset_index()
```

`groupby()` Takes the specified columns and groups the DataFrame based on unique combinations of these two columns.

`reset_index()` method is used to convert the grouped data back to a regular DataFrame and reset the index.

Answer (score 0):

After `df_matched` you can do the following:

1. Make a dictionary with each unique `id_treated` as keys and all `id_control`s in a list as values.
2. Therafter you can make an empty dataframe with the same columns as `df_matched`.
3. From there on, iterate over each key and value in the dict and check whether the `id_control` is present (except the current one) in the dictionary, together with a check of the `id_treated` is also present in the new dataframe. If so, continue the loop.
4. If not, add the corresponding row (matching those ids) to the new dataframe.

The code:

```
dict_from_df = df_matched.groupby('id_treated')['id_control'].apply(list).to_dict()
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_matched.columns)

counter, add_count = 0, 0
for k, v_list in dict_from_df.items():
    for v in v_list:
        if counter == 0:
            result_df.loc[counter] = df_matched[(df_matched['id_treated'] == k) & \
                                                (df_matched['id_control'] == v)].iloc[0]
            add_count =+ 1
        else:
            if any(v in values for key, values in dict_from_df.items() if key != k) \
               and k in result_df['id_treated'].values:
                continue
            else:
                result_df.loc[add_count] = df_matched[(df_matched['id_treated'] == k) & \
                                                      (df_matched['id_control'] == v)].iloc[0]
                add_count += 1
        counter += 1

result_df[['id_treated', 'group', 'id_control']]
```

Which will result in the dataframe you have provided (except the indices):

|  | id_treated | group | id_control |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a-1 | A | x-1 |
| 1 | a-2 | A | y-9 |
| 2 | a-3 | C | y-1 |
| 3 | b-1 | C | x-2 |
| 4 | b-1 | C | x-3 |
| 5 | b-2 | A | y-9 |

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [linear sum assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) problem, which you could solve with [`scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html).

The idea is to compute a matrix distance for each pair (per group), mask the values above threshold with Inf, and use the linear assignment algorithm to find the best pairs:

```
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

def get_match(g1, g2, thresh=0.1):
    s1 = g1.set_index('id')['score']
    s2 = g2.set_index('id')['score']
    a1 = s1.to_numpy()[:,None]
    
    diff = abs(a1-s2.to_numpy())/a1
    
    try:
        _, y = linear_sum_assignment(np.where(diff<=thresh, diff, np.inf))
    except ValueError:
        return pd.Series(float('nan'), index=g1.index)
    
    return pd.Series(s2.index[y], index=g1.index)

gc = df_control.groupby('group')

df_treatment['id_control'] = (
    df_treatment
    .groupby('group')
    .apply(lambda g: get_match(g, gc.get_group(g.name)))
    .droplevel(0)
)

print(df_treatment)
```

Output:

```
    id group  score id_control
0  a-1     A    200        x-1
1  a-2     A    230        y-9
2  a-3     C    210        y-1
3  b-1     C    390        x-2
4  b-2     A    202        y-8
```

Comment: Thank you! This describes the problem well and produces a solution with 93% unique matches.

One thing not mentioned is that df_control can contain the same id but with a different group or score. I think the repeats of id are cases where it's the same id but different in group and score. This isn't a problem but ideally we'd not have the same control_id repeated


Can we include other parameters besides 'score' in the distance matrix? These would be numerical and so possible to calculate distances between them.

Comment: Can you provide specific examples in a reproducible format?

Comment: `df_treatment = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['a-1', 'a-2', 'a-3', 'b-1', 'b-2'],
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A'],
    'score': [200, 230, 210, 390, 202],
    'production': [22.2, 41.1, 19.7, 16.3, 34.4, 35.0]
})`  


`df_control = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['x-1', 'y-9', 'y-8', 'y-1', 'x-2', 'x-3'],
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'score': [180, 218, 210, 200, 400, 380],
    'production': [22.3, 41.6, 19.4, 16.1, 34.2, 35.2]
})`  


This idea would be to get a closer matched control. The threshold could be kept the same for both parameters.

Comment: Can you check the first dataset, it seems invalid?

Comment: Done, production had 1 too many values

`df_treatment = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['a-1', 'a-2', 'a-3', 'b-1', 'b-2'],
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A'],
    'score': [200, 230, 210, 390, 202],
    'production': [22.2, 41.1, 19.7, 16.3, 34.4]
})`  


`df_control = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['x-1', 'y-9', 'y-8', 'y-1', 'x-2', 'x-3'],
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'score': [180, 218, 210, 200, 400, 380],
    'production': [22.3, 41.6, 19.4, 16.1, 34.2, 35.2]
})`

Comment: Can you actually [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77533051/edit) the question with that? And please provide the exact expected output

Comment: Also I don't understand how this new example demonstrates the "*df_control can contain the **same id** but with a **different group or score***". Regarding the inclusion of other parameters, yes this is possible but unless really trivial, please let's stick to the current case for now and once functional we can see how to implement that, eventually through a follow-up question.

Comment: Hi there, df_control has been edited to include this behaviour now.

Currently this df_control would produce 
```    
id group  score id_control
0  a-1     A    200        x-1
1  a-2     A    230        y-9
2  a-3     C    210        x-1
3  b-1     C    390        x-2
4  b-2     A    202        y-8
```
Where x-1 is repeated, but with one group c and one group a